# GIT Pull - Fatal error - Reference has invalid format: 'refs/tags/before string intern functions and memory gz'

Tags: git, netbeans, github, git-merge

I'm using github on few projects and now i have a strange problem. Normally i use netbeans to do the pull and push but, when netbeans have some errors, i go manually to the command line and do the pull.

When i do a "git pull" i receive:

```
fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/tags/before string intern functions and memory gz'
```

This happens before i add the github credentials and nothing happens.

I tested using the normal git command line tool and the github GUI software too. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup of the code entire folder
2. Navigate to the folder that is described in error within the folder .git

> ./.git/refs/tags/
>
> You know that the file "before string intern functions and memory gz" is problematic... One solution is DELETE IT. If you are not using the tag lose it will not be a problem.
>
> After do that, do a normal add, commit, pull, push and everything will work :)